# Why the scan stopped working (using memory allocation)?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, scanf

I've done this code to read an array, it works properly in the small tests (3x3), however i need it to read a 15x15 one. After 150 scans it has stopped working, returned 3221225477 and closed.
What is happening? How to fix it?

```
int ** ler(){
    FILE *a;
    a = fopen("matriz.txt", "r"); 
    int **N;
    int b, c, d;

    N = malloc(15 * sizeof(int));
    for (b = 0; b < 15; b++){
        N[b] = malloc(15 * sizeof(int));
     }
     for (b = 0; b < 15; b++){
        
        for (c = 0; c < 15; c++){
            fscanf(a, "%i", &d);
            N[b][c] = d; 
            
          }     
     }  
    return N;
}
```

Comment: When you say it returns 3221225477, are you saying that this is the numeric value of N (e.g., what you would get from `printf("%lld", (long long)ler())`?  Because you're returning a pointer (which is what N is), the return value of `ler()` will be the address of N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this problem:

**Wrong size allocation**

```
int **N;  //      vvvvvvvvvvv This is the size of an int       
//N = malloc(15 * sizeof(int));
N = malloc(15 * sizeof *N);
          //    ^^^^^^^^^ The size of a pointer is needed here
```

---

With OP's code, when the size of an `int` < size of an `int *`, the allocation is undersized.

Avoid that mistake and code with `*N` rather than attempting to match the type.

```
// Nice idiom
ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * n);
         //  ^^^^^^^^^^^   The right size regardless of what `ptr` pointers to.
```

---

Call `fclose(a)` when done reading.

Comment: I think you meant sizeof(int*), right? I am not familiar with sizeof writing this way..

Comment: @Pranavappu I do mean `sizeof *N`. That is the size of the object pointed to by `N`.  Notice no type involved in that code to get wrong like OP did.

Comment: Yes, `sizeof(*N)`. I meant the same thing. So you don't need parenthesis for sizeof?

Comment: @Pranavappu `sizeof object` OK.  `sizeof *some_pointer` OK.  `()` needed with type: `sizeof (int)`.